# 3D pill shape in inkspace

Tags: inkscape, 3d, illustration

I am trying to replicate a figure shown at the top in Inkspace. So far I have managed to do what appears at the bottom. Is there a way that an extrude effect  `Extensions -> Generate from Path -> Extrude`, that was applied to make the base in the figure, following a tutorial extruding paths with edges, be used for the rounded rectangles?

[image]

The SVG file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZfQgx_OZDwSC0tTHZQdndwWG8/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need any 3D extrude function to do something as simple as that. The graphic could easily be made with two rounded rectangles placed one on top of the other.

Create the top shape first, and click and drag the circular corner control points to get the shape.

Click `Edit` > `Copy`, then `Edit` > `Paste in place`. Click and drag the bottom right control (see control circled in red below) to make a deeper shape.

Send the new shape to the back by clicking `Object` > `Lower`.

Apply a gradient fill to the new shape. And edit the gradient as required.

[image: Example showing steps for construction of graphic]

Here's the link to the SVG if you want it: http://www.filedropper.com/pill

This was made with Inkscape 0.92

Comment: Caramba! - drawed the same image and wrote nearly the same text !

Comment: ah . . . great minds must think alike. LOL